# React Native mini-app / microapp structure

Tags: react-native, micro-frontend

I'm trying to build a react native app which contains:

1/ A core app (which have multiple services)

2/ A mini-app to serve individual service above.

The benefit of this approach is to:

- Reduce the size of the core app (which will be published on stores)
- Easier to manage those services (each team will be in charge for one or two services)

Through my research, I found out that there is an app which is using this approach:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mservice.momotransfer

After debugging with Charles proxy, I discover that they call an api to load a bundle (.jsbundle file for iOS platform) and then load the mini-app from this bundle.

However, I have not yet found any official documentation or tutorial for implementing this structure. I would be very thankful if you have any keywords, medium posts, example github repos about this matter.

Answer (score 4):

you are finding as same mine
Look at this page https://github.com/smallnew/react-native-multibundler